# Как настроить VS2015 или Resharper для добавления пустой строки в конец файла?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Как настроить *VS2015* или *Resharper* для добавления пустой строки в конец файла?

Comment: Неужели настолько лень нажать enter?

Comment: @Qwertiy иногда бывает неудобно после возвращаться к файлу только потому, что забыл в конце пустую строку добавить